# Multiple nearly-identical views for the same view-model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a view-model with properties exposed, and I originally had a single view using that view-model. This view has several resources in it, followed by:

```
<!-- View1.xaml -->
<!-- several resources specific to View1 -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <!-- left side -->
   <!-- right side -->
</StackPanel>
```

Leaving this alone, I need to present the same information such that only the left side is displayed, and the right side shows up as a tooltip when hovering over what was originally the left side:

```
<!-- View2.xaml -->
<!-- same View1 resources -->
<!-- original left side -->
    <!-- original left side.ToolTip -->
        <!-- original right side -->
    <!--/original left side.ToolTip -->
<!--/code for original left side -->
```

As a first attempt, I did this by copying my original view to a new view and making the change.

The view using this originally used this, and still does:

```
<DataTemplate ...>
   <View1 />
</DataTemplate>
```

I now have a new separate view containing this:

```
<DataTemplate ...>
   <View2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

I don't want to copy/paste/maintain the View1 and View2 resources separately since they're identical. I'd prefer they were in a single place, so what's the best practice in this situation?

Should I move the resources to a separate file and reference them in View1.xaml and View2.xaml, or should I modify View1.xaml to support the alternative tooltip and somehow call it from both places like this:

```
<!-- file1.xaml -->
<DataTemplate ...>
   <View1 />
</DataTemplate>

<!-- file2.xaml -->
<DataTemplate ...>
   <View1 Layout="Brief" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If the latter, what do I do to support a new `Layout` attribute in `View1`?

Note that I don't need to change between these views at runtime, so I believe I don't need a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to assess without more code. It sounds like the two modes of the view could be switched in the ViewModel. Which would be one VM and one View file?

Comment: jia , i recommend you one thing if your project is big and as you have not much experience it would be better to have multiple viewmodels and views that may have 30-40 % common code.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you just need to put the common resources into the `Application.Resources` section of your App.xaml file. All resources defined there are available application wide, so all of your views can reference them. For the full story, see the [How to: Use Application Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, but from that page:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GelButton" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,2,1,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
...
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In this example, the `GelButton Style` would be available to every `Button` defined in every `Window` and `UserControl` in the Application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think we want to put the resources there for exactly that reason--these were specific to one view only, now two very similar views. They're not general-purpose enough to warrant the privilege of being global to the app. Can I still factor them out into a separate XAML file that these two XAML files can reference, similar to #including a shared .h file in C++?

Comment: There's no rule that says that every view has to use *all* of the `Application.Resources`. It's totally fine to put resources there that are only used by two views. Alternatively, take a look at the [How do I separate out resources into multiple files in WPF?](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/05/27/How-do-I-separate-out-resources-into-multiple-files-in-WPF.aspx) on the LearnWPF website.